# Wait until a subroutine is not used by other process

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have an MPI-parallelized code where it loops through n persons, and for each one it calls some subroutines to do some calculations and after all inside the loop calls a post-processing subroutine.

In the post-processing subroutine, I write the output I want in the following way:

```
person_number var1 var2
```

Let's say that every person belongs to a different rank. The problem is that when I write the file for person1, then maybe process of `rank3` that includes `person3` variables is executing the post-processing subroutine, so it overwrites my data of person1.

What I want is to find a way, to pause other processes before calling the post-processing subroutine, and then once this subroutine is not used by the previous rank, to run it for the next rank and so on.

This is a sketch of the code:

```
call MPI_Init(ierr)

do i = 1, npersons

call subroutine1(arg1,arg2,arg3)

! call it only if post_process not executed by other process
! otherwise wait until it ends and then call it 
call post_process(i, var1, var2)

enddo

call MPI_Finalize(ierr)


subroutine post_process(i, var1, var2)
integer:: i
real*8:: var1, var2
write(111,*) i, var1, var2
end subroutine post_process
```

Comment: There's an answer below that addresses the problem as posed, but you're trying - if I understand you correctly - to serialize the postprocessing step to accommodate serial I/O.  I'm not sure that's the right approach here.  I think you'd be best off parallizing the I/O instead, either by writing each rank's output to a separate file and then combining afterwards, or by using MPI-IO to coordinate the output.

Comment: @JonathanDursi thank you for your answer. This is just an example of the code. It is parallelized in all modules/subroutines that need a lot of computational time. Therefore, it is ok just for the post-processing to be serialized as it doesn't take so much time. Though, it's true it would be better to use MPI-IO but I was searching for an easy implementable alternative. Writing output for each rank is an option but I don't want to generate so much files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reading your comment: " Also, I am wondering if for example process 3 is faster than process 2, if i can use the same way but as soon rank 1 finishes with the routine to notify rank 3 to run the routine and then rank 3 to notify rank 2. Is there any automatic way of this? to know which rank waits before the post-processing step longer?"

This can be addressed exactly by letting all the I/O be performed on process with irank==0 **and** using buffered sends.

In this case you don't want to let the processes wait, no barriers here, but you want to let them dispatch their result as soon as it's ready, and then continue calculating. When it's time for process 0, it will receive all the buffered data and write them, then it write its own data. You can try to use standard MPI_SEND (it's buffered up to a prefixed size), but the best way is to use MPI_BSEND and attach a correctly sized buffer with [MPI_BUFFER_ATTACH()](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Buffer_attach.html). Something like this:

```
subroutine post_process(i, var1, var2, irank)
integer:: i, irank
real*8:: var1, var2
integer:: ir
real*8:: var1r, var2r
character buffer(100)
integer ipos
boolean flag

if (irank .gt. 0) then
  ipos = 0
  call MPI_PACK(i, 1, MPI_INTEGER, buffer, 100, ipos, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  call MPI_PACK(var1, 1, MPI_REAL8, buffer, 100, ipos, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  call MPI_PACK(var2, 1, MPI_REAL8, buffer, 100, ipos, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  call MPI_BSend( buffer, ipos, MPI_PACKED, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr) 
else
  do
    call MPI_IPROBE(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, flag, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
    if (flag .eq. false) exit
    call MPI_RECV(buffer, 100, MPI_PACKED, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
    ipos = 0
    call MPI_UNPACK(buffer, 100, ipos, ir, 1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    call MPI_UNPACK(buffer, 100, ipos, var1r, 1, MPI_REAL8, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    call MPI_UNPACK(buffer, 100, ipos, var2r, 1, MPI_REAL8, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    write(111,*) ir, var1r, var2r      
  enddo
  write(111,*) i, var1, var2
end if
end subroutine post_process
```

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what i wanted to do. i wasn't aware of MPI_IPROBE.

Answer (score 2):

I'd perform this task serializing with barriers. Assuming you have got `irank` the result from `MPI_COMM_RANK()` and `nprocs` from `MPI_COMM_SIZE()`:

```
call MPI_Init(ierr)

do i = 1, npersons
call subroutine1(arg1,arg2,arg3)

do ir = 0, nprocs-1
if (ir .eq. irank) then 
  ! call it only if post_process not executed by other process
  ! otherwise wait until it ends and then call it 
  call post_process(i, var1, var2)
endif
call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
enddo

enddo
```

All the processes wait at the `MPI_BARRIER()`, until the *irank-th* completes, and reach the barrier too.

I have to say that since all the processes write on a shared filesystem in `post_process` this is not guaranteed to work: the synchronization imposed at MPI level is usually very fast (isn't MPI optimized for this?), and can be faster than the synchronization present in a shared filesystem (being it NFS, GPFS,...), especially on large clusters. Furthermore performing it with a plain fortran write to a shared file... quite sure you can randomly incur in file corruptions, because of caching and timings on the different hosts.

The typical way to approach it is to let only processor with irank==0 write to the file, all the others send data to be written to it. Better, using MPI2 I/O.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to initialize the MPI environment properly, by adding the following lines:

```
! Initialization of MPI
call MPI_INIT(ierr) 
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, numproc,ierr)
```

The function `MPI_COMM_RANK` will return a variable `rank`, which is an identifier for each process (i.e. each `person` of your example). You can use this variable for defining the order in which the processes execute the program. Also, since code in a MPI program is executed by all processes unless you tell them otherwise, you don't need a `do` loop to call your first subroutine.

You can use a call to `MPI_RECV` to block the execution of the program for each process until they receive a message. The trick is to work with the variable `rank` which indicates the number of each process (in your example, it seems to be numbers from 1 to n - be careful, it is likely that the ordering of ranks starts at 0). Tell your processes to pause and wait for a message, except the first process, which is allowed to execute the post-processing subroutine. Once process 1 is done with writing, tell it to send a message to process 2. As soon as process 2 receives the message, it will start executing the subroutine (which is now safe to do, since 1 is done) and send a message to process 3, and so on.

You can try to implement something like this:

```
integer:: tag
character(1):: mess

call subroutine1(arg1,arg2,arg3)  

tag=22    ! or any integer you like
mess='a'  ! The content here doesn't matter

if(rank .gt. 1) call MPI_RECV(mess,1,MPI_CHARACTER,rank-1,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,stat,ierr)

do k = 1,npersons
  if (rank .eq. k) then
    call post_process(var1, var2)
    if(rank .lt. npersons) then
      call MPI_SEND(mess,1,MPI_CHARACTER,rank+1,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
    end if
  end if
end do
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a really neat solution to what i want to do. In the MPI initialization I also had these lines, didn't put them in the code above for space economy. I don't understand why I don't need to include the 1st subroutine in one loop. Also, I am wondering if for example process 3 is faster than process 2, if i can use the same way but as soon rank 1 finishes with the routine to notify rank 3 to run the routine and then rank 3 to notify rank 2. Is there any automatic way of this? to know which rank waits before the post-processing step longer?

Comment: I had the same problem as you present it in your comment and couldn't come up with a solution, so I'd also be glad if someone could help here. To your question: if I follow you correctly, every process in your example represents one person. However, every process will execute all of the code unless you specify which processes execute a certain part (for example, using `if(rank==1)`). In your example, each process call the subroutine `npersons` times, which doesn't seem to be what you want to do. I hope I didn't misunderstand the problem,otherwise I should probably revise my answer.

Comment: @m.chips see my answer "reading your comment..." (I have posted a second answer after reading your comments!). That's a non-blocking, non-ordered solution. Hope it can be useful and I have not put errors (untested, but logically it's ok).